# How can I transfer my login system from sqlexpress to my own server?

Tags: asp.net

I am fairly new to the login system visual studio comes with and I've been wondering if is possible to transfer all the user information created automatically by visual studio from sqlexpress to my own database?, I've noticed that ASPNETDB.MDF contains the database information created for users and I wish to use it or store it in my own sqlserver instead of sqlexpress.

Ultimately my goal is to change the following connection string to my own connection string containing the name of my own server and database:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated           Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Alternate Solution: If you are using ./SQLEXPRESS detach ASPNETDB.MDF from your project, create a new database inside the server you want to, run aspnet_regsql with the new database you just created, and MODIFY THE CONNECTIONSTRINGS in your web.config to access your new database. That did it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  The stock ASP.NET membership tables in your SQLEXPRESS database are generated using the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool located in `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\(FrameworkVersion)`.  So you should be able to run this tool on your pointing to your new sql server.  Then backup and restore the data from the ASPNETDB database (as long as your sqlexpress and sql server versions match).  [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) is a good overall article about the generation of the membership tables.

Comment: After running the aspnet_regsql on my own database I get an error saying "System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'". Why is that?

Comment: Are you trying to attach at the same time as generating new tables?

Comment: Again, I would try reading through [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)

Comment: Ah, I think perhaps your connection string needs changing.  Guessing here, but perhaps your new database is not located in the App_Data directory?

Comment: Thanks for the article; I am reading through it. My new database is located in App_Data and I am not attaching at the same time as generating new tables. I simply ran aspnet_regsql pointing to my new database and I changed the connection string to my database but left the attachdbfilename in the connection string. I agree that I should read the article first before playing around.

Comment: I read through the tutorial and I had no luck. I cant connect to the new .mdf because the file is being used. I am not sure what is using it since I closed everything and reopened VS. I think part of the problem has to do with the fact that the .mdf file has a connection string using still ./SQLExpress and I dont know how to change that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11473/discussion-between-y-y-and-dtryon)